# How to create multiple value dictionary from pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Lets say I have a pandas data frame with 2 columns(column A and Column B):
For values in column 'A' there are multiple values in column 'B'.
I want to create a dictionary with multiple values for each key those values should be unique as well. Please suggest me a way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to groupby columns A:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 4], [5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  4
2  5  6

In [3]: g = df.groupby('A')
```

Apply `tolist` on each of the group's column B:

```
In [4]: g['B'].tolist()  # shorthand for .apply(lambda s: s.tolist()) "automatic delegation"
Out[4]:
A
1    [2, 4]
5       [6]
dtype: object
```

And then call `to_dict` on this Series:

```
In [5]: g['B'].tolist().to_dict()
Out[5]: {1: [2, 4], 5: [6]}
```

If you want these to be unique, use `unique` (Note: this will create a numpy array rather than a list):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 2], [5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: g = df.groupby('A')

In [13]: g['B'].unique()
Out[13]:
A
1    [2]
5    [6]
dtype: object

In [14]: g['B'].unique().to_dict()
Out[14]: {1: array([2]), 5: array([6])}
```

Other alternatives are to use `.apply(lambda s: set(s))`, `.apply(lambda s: list(set(s)))`, `.apply(lambda s: list(s.unique()))`...

Comment: @DSM I think it is actually the `Series.tolist` which is being applied to each group in the groupby (rather magically)... You can do that with quite a few Series/DataFrame methods on a groupby (I think it's just shorthand for `.apply(lambda s: s.tolist())`).

Comment: Aaah, so it's the automatic delegation which is confusing me.

Comment: I found one solution but it's not appending unique values. Please suggest me a way to append unique values                               df=dataframe[['A','B']]
for i in range(len(df['A'])):
 if df.loc[i][0] in dict.keys():
  dict[df.loc[i][0]].append(df.loc[i][1])
 else:
  dict[df.loc[i][0]]=[df.loc[i][1]]

Comment: What is your opinion about solution that I posted(in my previous comment)? I also found way to make it unique. just add one more if condition uder if as if df.loc[i][1] not in dict[df.loc[i][0]]:

Comment: @Akshay If you wanted to do it that way, you could also use a defaultdict(list) or defaultdict(set) and avoid the if/else :)

Answer (score 3):

You can actually loop over df.groupby object and collect the value as list.

In[1]:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 2], [5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
{k: list(v) for k,v in df.groupby("A")["B"]}
```

Out[1]:

```
{1: [2, 2], 5: [6]}
```